# C Struct Missing Properties in Swift Conversion

Tags: c, swift, struct, swift3

I'm using a C library in my Swift 3 application. One of the `struct`s defined in the library is defined thusly:

```
struct termRow {
    void *bitmaps[BITMAP_PTRS];
    int flags;
    uint64_t chars[];
};
```

In my Swift code, when I reference a property of this `termRow` type, I have access to the `bitmaps` and `flags`, but the `chars` array is nowhere to be found! In Xcode, the autocomplete tells the story -- no `chars` value:

[image]

My assumption here is that Swift is unable to translate `uint64_t` arrays? If that is the case, what can I do to make it work in my Swift code, without screwing things up for the rest of the library?

Comment: Maybe it just doesn't like the flexible array member.

Comment: What's the library? Do you have the full headers for it? Have you tried using it in a C, C++, or Objective-C program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume from the image that your `row` variable is a local instance of `struct termRow`. Are you sure the `chars` array was initialized? An array at the end of a struct with no defined bounds is an array of indeterminate length; If it is not initialized (in the case of a local) or allocated (in the case of a pointer), then it technically doesn't exist. Maybe that's what Xcode is trying to tell you.

Comment: Indeed, giving the array a size makes it show up. Alas! Thanks.

Comment: No sweat. Note also that "indeterminate" doesn't mean "variable". Once the array is bounded, either through initialization or allocation, the size is fixed from that point on for a given instance.